# How to establish a condition to check two frame have huge difference in openCV?

Tags: opencv

I am new to openCV. I am currently developing an application to do something about video processing with openCV. I need a trigger to enable my other work when two frame have huge difference. I know there is a function named **cvAbsDiff** but it only creates a diff image. But I need is a condition like `|frame_{i}-frame_{i-1}| > TH`. How can I do this with **openCV?** Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get the diff image of two different frames, you can then compute the sum of pixels values and apply your threshold.

Comment: I think calculate the norm of frame is much better. The formula is sqrt(sum((pixel1(i)-pixel2(i))^2)) > TH

Comment: Yeah I found this from documentation: double norm(const Mat& src1, const Mat& src2, int normType=NORM_L2)